# Find white regions in image

Tags: image-processing

At the white regions of this image I want to add a few random arrows. 
I would like to realize two different of adding the random arrows:

- The arrows may not leave the white region
- The arrows have to leave the white region

-

```
 img = Import["ExampleData/spikey2.png"]
```

[image]

How can you do this with Mathematica?

In particular I would like to know how to detect the white regions, and how to store this information. If I give you an arrow can you tell me whether it crosses non-white parts of the image?

There is not much space for the arrows in this picture. It would be good to add a bit of white canvas to create some space for the arrows.

Comment: How about showing what you tried, and more importantly, what you expect to actually see.

Comment: I made a mistake in may question. I said I the arrows have to leave the white region, but in fact they should not. I corrected this. Sorry for that

Comment: @bills I don't how to find the white regions in an image. So I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

Extending s0rce with `ImageValuePosition` (new in 9.0).

```
Module[{w, h},
 {w, h} = ImageDimensions@img;
 img~ImageCompose~Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[.08], Opacity[.7],
    Map[Arrow[{#, # - .5 (# - .5 {w, h})}] &,
     RandomSample[ImageValuePositions[img, {1, 1, 1}], 20]]},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> {w, h},
   PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}}]]
```

[image: Spiked]

Arrows end half way to center.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/spikey2.png"];
arrowstarts = RandomChoice[ImageValuePositions[img, {1, 1, 1}], 10]
arrowends = RandomChoice[ImageValuePositions[img, {0, 0, 0}, 0.75], 10]
arrows = Graphics[
   MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {arrowstarts, arrowends}], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> {150, 135}, 
   Background -> Transparent, PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 135}}];
ImageCompose[img, arrows]
```

[image: spikiy]

Comment: Isn't your graphics missing `PlotRange`? `Graphics` without it displays max and min values and nothing further, which makes the composition a bit off, doesn't it.

Comment: @BoLe, um it appears to work, I just ran my code again on a fresh kernel and it worked.

Comment: It works, it composes the images but not correctly. To see this change `10` to `1` in both `RandomChoice` and run a few times if necessary.

Comment: @BoLe, you're right! fixed with `ImageValuePositions` and `PlotRange`.